# Printing our every third letter in Python for Grok

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm using Grok learning and I'm stuck on the task "Secret Agent". I have figured out most the code except I have a random space at the end which I can't remove. I have used `.rstrip()` and I'm really confused. Here is my code so far:

```
text = input("Message? ")
length = len(text)
for i in range (0, length, 3):
  decoded = text[i]
  print(decoded, end=' '[1:3])
```

Comment: It will be easier to help if you provide us with a bit more information. What is this "Secret Agent" task? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well our prgramme should look like this:                                                         Message? cxohawalkldflghemwnsegfaeap
c h a l l e n g e                                                                                              I need to add a space after each character plus I need to pick out every three letter to get the final result.

Comment: Ok, so I would say that [@MathiasEttinger](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32777962/1660507) answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway @makeMonday

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `range`, you can more easily iterate every 3 characters using the slice construct:

```
text[::3]
```

Once you have all your letters, you can `join` them, using any delimiter you want.

Your code should look like:

```
text = input("Message? ")
decoded = ' '.join(text[::3])
print(decoded)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and this really helped me. This is a simplified version of what I was doing. Thank you once again, I will use this in the future :)

Comment: nice solution - I thought joining would help but didn't know the python syntax

Comment: Thank you. If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1):

Here's Grok's explanation to your question:
"So, this question is asking you to loop over a string, and print out every third letter.
The easiest way to do this is to use for and range, letting range do all the heavy lifting and hard work!
We know that range creates a list of numbers, - we can use these numbers as indexes for the message!"

So if you are going to include functions like `print`, `len`, `end`, `range`, `input`,  `for` and `in` functions, your code should look somewhat similar to this:

```
line = input('Message? ')

result = line[0]
for i in range(3, len(line), 3):
  result += ' ' + line[i]
print(result)
```

Or this:

```
line = input('Message? ')
print(line[0], end='')
for i in range(3, len(line), 3):
  print(' ' + line[i], end='')
print()
```

Or maybe this:

```
code = input ('Message? ') [0::3]
msg = ""
for i in code: msg += " " + i
print (msg [1:])
```

All of these should work, and I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

instead of printing every loop try building up the string then printing it at the end, this will allow for easier control of the terminating space 
hint: prepend the space to your strings instead of appending it using something like

```
decoded += ' ' + text[i]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i'm still a bit confused, could you please explain a bit more. I'm sorry i'm just new to python :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
code = input ('Message? ') [0::3]
msg = ""
for i in code: msg += " " + i
print (msg [1:])
```